# An invisible character and can only be shown in sublime

Tags: php, mysql

In sublime the invisible character is shown as below:

[image: img-link]

And the character is here: ''

HEX CODE: `&#xDBFF;&#xDC1F`;

Decimal CODE: `&#56319;&#56351`;

When I update the table with a string contain this character in MySQL, the content after it will be cut off.

What the hell is this?

Comment: have you tried using a prepare statement to bind the string you are inserting?  that would probably fix it...

Comment: I have used $this->db->escape() in codeignter framework ,but no effect

Comment: Escape does not bind the variable. That won't do what you need.

Comment: Try viewing this file in some hex editing software

Comment: take a look at what this person did to bind his value http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11514253/does-codeigniter-support-named-query-binding

Comment: i tried to bind in ci,but no effect
$sql = "update entities set main = ? where guid = 1021808";
$ret = $this->db->query($sql, array('beforeafter'));